# IQKeyBoardManager library issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, iqkeyboardmanager

I used `IQKeyBoardManager` library in `objective C`. And in this app I have use MFSideMenu library for Side menu. but When i click on text field or textview the side menu scroll down automatically. And not showing completely. After removing IQKeyBoardManager Side Menu work perfect.

Can Anybody provide the link for IQDropDownTextField Library which will no effect on side menu.

Comment: Can you show screenshot?

Comment: Side Menu not show completely when we scrolled. Can you please give the link for latest IQDropDownTextField library.

Comment: from their github "
If IQKeybaordManager conflicts with other third-party library, then it's developer responsibility to enable/disable IQKeyboardManager when presenting/dismissing third-party library UI. Third-party libraries are not responsible to handle IQKeyboardManager."

Comment: Ok , But when i used IQKeyboardManager using pod then the app work perfectly. So i want to the latest IQKeyboardManager library without pod.

Comment: Can you provide the link please.

Comment: When we run on iPhone 4 the app run perfectly. But on iPhone 5s or iPhone 6s , this is not work perfectly. Can you help me.

Comment: @HariMohan did you find out solution?

Comment: No sir, I have not any solution..

Comment: plz elaborate your issue in detail

Comment: When i click on text field or textview, the side menu scroll down automatically below, it means the side menu table not show completely.

Comment: @HariMohan Did you get the solution ?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel did you got the solution

Comment: @VijayvirSingPantlia still you stuck?

Comment: Yes , I am using IQKeyBoardManager , and today I integrate PayU UI SDK ..  IQKeyBoardManager not supporting Payu sdk 
Is there any keyboard vice disable or enable  IQKeyBoardManager functionality

Comment: @VijayvirSingPantlia you need textfield inside scrollview?

Comment: @VijayvirSingPantlia mention username in comment.so i can get notification

Comment: @VijayvirSingPantlia this one is good library.https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding